# Symfony splitted embedded form

Tags: symfony, twig

I work with a symfony embedded form to manage my translated fields for a given entity. My principal entity has a boolean field and I have multiple text fields for each translation.

I do not use the translatable doctrine extension and I do not want to use it.

In my FormType, I use a CollectionType to embed the translated fields in my form, and in the template, I use the form theme to customize the HTML.

This is my problem : I would like to group fields in my form to optimize UX but once I call the form_widget on my field, I cannot use it a second time. I would like to show 2 fields for a given language and then another field for another language further in the form. How can I solve my problem ?

This is a twig example that illustrate my problem.

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block _service_translations_entry_widget %}
<div>
    {% if name == 0 %}
    <div class="s12 m6 l6">
        {{ form_label(form.title) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.title) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.title) }}
    </div>

    <div class="s12 m6 l6">
        {{ form_label(form.subtitle) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.subtitle) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.subtitle) }}
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if name == 1 %}
    <div class="s12 m12 l12">
        {{ form_label(form.desc) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.desc) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.desc) }}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

{{ form_start() }}
{{ form_errors(form) }} 

<div>
    <div class="s12 m12 l12">
        {{ form_label(form.doubleBlock) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.doubleBlock) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.doubleBlock) }}
    </div>
</div>

<div id="block-1">
    {{ form_widget(form.translations) }}
</div>

<div>
    <div class="s12 m6 l6">
        {{ form_label(form.activedStyle) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.activedStyle) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.activedStyle) }}
    </div>

    <div class="s12 m6 l6">
        {{ form_label(form.checkoutOption) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.checkoutOption) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.checkoutOption) }}
    </div>
</div>

<div id="block-2">
    {{ form_widget(form.translations) }}
</div>

{{ form_widget(form.save) }}

{{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

{% endblock body %}

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you can’t reuse a field.

My suggested approach would be to add an additional field to the form, translations_extra, which either isn’t mapped to or persisted by the entity. Extract the data in the controller on form submission and then add it to the translations collection before persisting.